# My site crashed

Tags: 7, commerce, wsod

My site crashed trying to enable Commerce modules (like 10 at a time). Now I get white screen of death. How do I restore my site? I know it had only 64MB PHP memory, does increasing it will restore the website or is the database already broken and game over?

Comment: First thing to do is check your apache error logs and post the errors. That will tell you what the problems are that need fixing.

Comment: Memory log says memory limit exceeded for various modules. But I can't increase the memory myself so I let you know if this restored the website later.

Comment: Delete Commerce modules directory then run the browsers .If it is may be work

Comment: Don't do what above user said.. It will lead to more problems since you are deleting modules and entries exist in database.. @Senthil : Please don't misguide if you are not sure what you are talking about..

Comment: You can increase memory limit. Use following function and put it in settings.php file. If you have no idea how much memory required for your site then set memory limit as -l (unlimited). ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
//ini_set('memory_limit','-1');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing PHP memory limit to 192MB solved the problem.